# meaning of "that (adjective) thing going"

Tags: meaning, idioms

I'm reading a story in English: it's not my native language. Two guys are spending time in a hot tub and talking and joking, and one guy says to the other

> "Oh, uh huh.  So, is this where I get to kiss him?” He teased.  “He does have that Shakespearean England thing going with the accent."

What does “He does have that Shakespearean England thing going with the accent.” mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This pattern, "that {adjective} thing going (on)" means "that mannerism".

Sometimes (as in your quote) it is used to refer to a manner that is charming, but sometimes to a manner that is annoying, or disconcerting, or unlikable, etc etc.

> She's got that Wicked Witch of the West thing going on.
>
> He's got that Napoleon thing going on.
>
> She's got that Marlene Dietrich thing going on with the way she holds her cigarette.

This is a very casual way of speaking. It is often the cant of a subculture.